# Is $\langle x,y \rangle=\overline{\langle y,x \rangle}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

can anyone help me?

Be $(X,\|.\|)$ a normed space that satisfies the parallelogram law.  Let's define $\Phi : X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by:

$\Phi (x,y)=\dfrac{1}{4}[ \|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2]$

Prove

$\Phi(x,y)=\overline{\Phi(y,x)}$

I resolved

$\overline{\Phi(x,y)}=\dfrac{1}{4}[ \|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2-i\|x+iy\|^2+i\|x-iy\|^2]$

Comment: @MinecraftPlayer69 I'd say OP has to show $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}$ and it is $\|x+iy\|^2=\|y-ix\|^2$ that allows him to do so.

Comment: Question says $\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$

Comment: @MinecraftPlayer69 I saw that. But this implies that $\Phi$ is real valued. Is it? Besides: the  complex inner product must be Hermitian not real valued.

Comment: @MinecraftPlayer69  Question is wrong

Comment: Counterexample: $|\cdot|$ on $\Bbb{C}$.  $\Phi(i,1)=i$.

Comment: And obviously, $\Phi(1,i)=-i$ as it should.

Answer (score 2):

A [Hermitian inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) must have the
conjugate symmetry
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\overline{\langle y,x\rangle}\,.
$$
For $\Phi(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle$ this is not hard to show by noticing that
$$
\|x+iy\|^2=\|i(-ix+y)\|^2=|i|^2\|(-ix+y)\|^2=\|y-ix\|^2\,.
$$
Likewise,
$$
\|x-iy\|^2=\|-y-ix\|^2=\|y+ix\|^2\,.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\Phi (x,y)&=\dfrac{1}{4}[ \|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|x+iy\|^2-i\|x-iy\|^2]\\
&=\dfrac{1}{4}[ \|x+y\|^2-\|x-y\|^2+i\|y-ix\|^2-i\|y+ix\|^2]
\end{align}
from which $\Phi(x,y)=\overline{\Phi(y,x)}$ follows.